# Set PHP variable to MySQL wildcard '%'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to query posts using PDO where the database column 'tags' = something.

My problem is: I want my query to work even if there's no `$_GET['tag']` request is set and here's my code.

```
if (!isset($_GET['tag'])) {
    $tags = '%';
} else {
    $tags = $_GET['tag'];
}

$get_recipes = $con->prepare ("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE tags = ?");
$get_recipes->execute(array($tags));
$recipes = $get_recipes->fetchAll();
```

Is it valid to set the PHP variable `$tags` to the MySQL wildcard `%`? if not possible then what should I do to make my query work?

When I run that code and there's not `$_GET['tag']` is written the query will not fetch any posts from the database.

Comment: What are you going to set your wildcard too? A random tag?

Comment: I want it to be like that.. if there's no tag is selected then to show all posts regardless of the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Wildcards in Prepared Statements With PDO**

When using a wildcard in MySQL you must use the `LIKE` operator. It is correct to bind the wildcard with parameters in PDO.

You would prepare your statement like so.

```
$get_recipes = $con->prepare ("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE tags LIKE ?");
```

And then you would bind your parameter using the `%` character, like so.

```
 $get_recipes->execute(array('%'));
```

While that is the correct way to use a wildcard in the way you've proposed, that is not the correct solution to do what you're trying to do.

**How to achieve what you're trying to achieve**

In your code it looks like you want to select all rows if  `$_POST['tags']` is not set, and if it is set you want to select all rows that have the `tags` column set to the value of `$_POST['tags']`. To do this, you would want to prepare your statement inside the conditional, like so.

```
if (!isset($_GET['tag'])) {
    $get_recipes = $con->prepare ("SELECT * FROM recipes");
    $get_recipes->execute();
} else {
    $get_recipes = $con->prepare ("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE tags = ?");
    $get_recipes->execute(array($_GET['tag']));
}

$recipes = $get_recipes->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Using the `LIKE` operator actually solved it! My query now is `SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE tags LIKE ?`. One query only and it worked with what I've done before `$tags = '%';`

Comment: Please note that with that you will be excluding all rows that have a `NULL` value for the `tags` column, and also all rows that have an empty string for the `tags` column.

Comment: Got the Idea. I used your method now with `if` and `else` 2 queries to avoid missing the rows with `NULL` and empty strings.