# MySQL select all values associated with variable if provided, or select everything (including empty) if not provided

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to create an array of data based on the output of a MySQL query.

I want the user to be able to specify their city from a drop down box and in this case the entries to be returned only for the relevant city.

Critically if the user doesn't select a city (i.e. leave it blank) I want them to see *all* the data rather than *none* of the data.

**My Code**

```
    // Parameters for order
    $ordercity = ( ! empty( $_GET['city'] ) ) ? $_GET['city'] : '%'; // Set a wildcard if not provided
    $exclstatus   = 'wc-refunded'; // Set any excluded statuses

    // Get the order details
    $orderdata = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT 
        posts.post_status,
        posts.id as post_id,
        meta1.meta_value AS city, 
        meta2.meta_value AS company,
        meta3.meta_value AS email
        FROM 
        wp2_posts posts,
        wp2_postmeta meta1,
        wp2_postmeta meta2,
        wp2_postmeta meta3
        WHERE posts.ID = meta1.post_id    
            AND posts.post_status NOT LIKE '$exclstatus'
            AND meta1.meta_key LIKE '_billing_city'
            AND meta1.meta_value LIKE '$ordercity'
            AND meta1.post_id = posts.id
            AND meta2.meta_key LIKE '_billing_company'
            AND meta2.post_id = posts.id
            AND meta3.meta_key LIKE '_billing_email'
            AND meta3.post_id = posts.id
    ", ARRAY_A );
```

**The limitations of my current approach**

My current approach is to populate $ordercity with the '%' wildcard if the city has not been set.

This is limited because only records which have some value for _billing_city (i.e. aren't empty) are selected.

**My research**

This [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662526/set-php-variable-to-mysql-wildcard) which suggested using conditionals was interesting, but it would require me to have two very similar queries (one with `AND meta1.meta_value LIKE '$ordercity'` and one without) which seems unnecessary and could be very long winded if I have more than one variable.

I've also checked out W3 Schools advice on [SQL Wildcards](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) but I am failing to see any guidance on Wildcards that will select the field if it is 'anything or nothing'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with an answer for this which is inspired by Rahul's suggestion.

Basically, if the parameter is not set, I set it to '' using PHP. Then in the SQL, if that parameter is set to '' I continue, and if it isn't, I use that parameter

```
// Parameters for order - if it isn't set, set it to ''
$ordercompany = ( ! empty( $_GET['company'] ) ) ? $_GET['company'] : '';
$exclstatus   = 'wc-refunded'; // Set any excluded statuses


// Get the order details
$orderdata = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT 
    posts.post_status,
    posts.id as post_id,
    meta1.meta_value AS company, 
    meta2.meta_value AS city,
    meta3.meta_value AS email
    FROM 
    wp2_posts posts,
    wp2_postmeta meta1,
    wp2_postmeta meta2,
    wp2_postmeta meta3
    WHERE posts.ID = meta1.post_id    
        AND posts.post_status NOT LIKE '$exclstatus'
        AND meta1.meta_key LIKE '_billing_company'
        // This is the important bit!
        AND ('$ordercompany = '' OR meta1.meta_value LIKE '$ordercompany')
        AND meta1.post_id = posts.id
        AND meta2.meta_key LIKE '_billing_city'
        AND meta2.post_id = posts.id
        AND meta3.meta_key LIKE '_billing_email'
        AND meta3.post_id = posts.id
", ARRAY_A );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Dirty** trick.
Your query is a string.

```
if ($city != "") $wheee = "AND city = 'whatever' ";

[...]
WHERE posts.ID = meta1.post_id ".$wheee."   
    AND posts.post_status NOT LIKE '$exclstatus'
    AND meta1.meta_key LIKE '_billing_city'
[...]
```

Comment: Your solution proposes code with sql vulnerability posibilities.

Comment: I see your point, but it's a (dirty) methodology answer and the condition is merely there to show where $wheee comes from. Your comment stands as a rightful caveat.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a `OR` condition saying

```
AND (meta1.meta_value LIKE '$ordercity' OR meta1.meta_value IS NULL)
```

Comment: But wouldn't that select the null values even when the user has selected a specific city?

Comment: @Manav, believe that's what OP wants

Comment: @rahul. I didn't want to show empty values IF the city was selected, but I wanted to show them if the city was not selected. I've updated my question to include a solution based on your suggestion though. Thanks.